# Xen - "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'" error when trying to create domain with VNC enabled

Tags: debian, xen, python

I'm setting up a Debian Xen server for the first time, and so far it's gone smoothly. However, whenever I tried to enable VNC connections for a domain (by adding a `vfb=...` line to the config file), attempting to run `xm create` on the config file causes a crash with the following cryptic Python error:

`Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'`

Some Google searching revealed that it's a bug in option parsing in whatever Python script starts the domains, but that tells me nothing about how to fix it. If I comment out the "vfb" line in the config file, the domain will start without any issues. My full config file for the domain is below:

```
#
# Configuration file for the Xen instance devnode.sector91.com, created
# by xen-tools 4.2 on Thu Apr 26 15:40:33 2012.
#

#
#  Kernel + memory size
#


bootloader = '/usr/lib/xen-default/bin/pygrub'

vcpus       = '1'
memory      = '512'

#
#  Disk device(s).
#
root        = '/dev/xvda2 ro'
disk        = [
                  'phy:/dev/chimera/devnode.sector91.com-disk,xvda2,w',
                  'phy:/dev/chimera/devnode.sector91.com-swap,xvda1,w',
              ]


#
#  Physical volumes
#


#
#  Hostname
#
name        = 'devnode.sector91.com'

#
#  Networking
#
vif         = [ 'ip=192.168.254.95,mac=00:16:3E:96:1A:FF,bridge=br0' ]

#
# Remote VNC Access
#
vfb = [ 'type=vnc' ]

#
#  Behaviour
#
on_poweroff = 'destroy'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'
```

Any idea how to make this error stop? Is there something obvious I'm forgetting here?

(OS: Debian Squeeze, 32-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

`apt-get install xen-qemu-dm-4.0`

Comment: This fixed my original problem, but now I am unable to access the VNC server after starting the domU, even though the domain starts without errors. This may be the best I can get though; I switched to just running a VNC server on the domU itself. Much less hassle.

Comment: Your problem seems to be solved, but you might want to add following to your domU configuration: vfb=[ "type=vnc,vncunused=0,vncdisplay=1,vnclisten=0.0.0.0,keymap=ja" ]